# How can I get final embeddings file with vocabulary at the starting of each line?

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

Can someone tell me how can I add vocabulary to the embeddings? Like we have in word2vec Google C code.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to combine embeddings and metadata file together.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I was able to extract the embeddings information in the text file along with the tensor dimension as header. But could not get the way to save the metadata.